SDL2 Program Breaks Every Time I Try To Render Something
Every time i try to render a rectangle or line to the screen then the entire screen turns black and my background color won't work anymore.
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_timer.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  SDL_Window *window;
  SDL_Renderer  *renderer;
} Editor;

void handleInputs() {
  SDL_Event event;

  while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {

    switch (event.type) {

      case SDL_QUIT:
        exit(0);
        break;

      default: 
        break;
    }
  }
}

void draw(Editor* editor) {
  //Clear and fill Background
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(editor->renderer, 24, 24, 24, 255);
  SDL_RenderClear(editor->renderer);

  //Draw A Rectangle To The Screen
  /* SDL_Rect rect; */
  /* rect.x = 0; */
  /* rect.y = 0; */
  /* rect.w = 50; */
  /* rect.h = 50; */
  /**/
  /* SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(editor->renderer, 83, 83, 83, 255); */
  /* SDL_RenderDrawRect(editor->renderer, &rect); */
  /* SDL_RenderFillRect(editor->renderer, &rect); */
  /**/

  //Draw A Line
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(editor->renderer, 83, 83, 83, 255);
  /* SDL_RenderDrawLine(editor->renderer, 10, 10, 50, 50); */

  SDL_RenderPresent(editor->renderer);
}

int main(void) {
  Editor editor;

  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
    printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
  }

  editor.window = SDL_CreateWindow("EDITOR", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
  editor.renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(editor.window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

  while (1) {
    handleInputs();
    draw(&editor);
  }
}

If I remove the line that renders either the line or the rectangle then it will use my background color and everything will work fine.

Just a guess, because I never used SDL2. As all display updates are delayed, the second or third SDL_SetRenderDrawColor() may be overriding the first one. I would try using a SDL_RenderPresent() right after the SDL_RenderClear().
